# Human-readable filesize and line count

Tags: bash, wc, du

I want a bash command that will return a table, where each row is the human-readable filesize, number of lines, and filename. The table should be sorted by filesize.

I've been trying to do this using a combination of `du -hs`, `wc -l`, and `sort -h`, and `find`.

Here's where I'm at:

```
find . -exec echo $(du -h {}) $(wc -l {}) \; | sort -h
```

Comment: show us what you got

Comment: @eckes edited with non-working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach fell short not only because **the shell expanded your command substitutions (`$(...)`) *up front***, but more fundamentally because **you cannot pass *shell* command lines *directly* to `find`**:

**`find`'s `-exec` action can only invoke *external utilities* with *literal* arguments** - the only non-literal argument supported is the `{}` representing the filename(s) at hand.

[choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38938025/45375) fixes your immediate problem by **invoking a separate shell instance in each iteration**, to which the shell command to execute is passed as a *string argument* (`-exec bash -c '...' \;`).
While this works (assuming you pass the `{}` value as an *argument* rather than embedding it in the command-line string), it is also **quite *inefficient*, because *multiple child processes* are created *for each input file***.

(While there *is* a way to have `find` pass (typically) all input files to a (typically) *single* invocation of the specified external utility - namely with terminator `+` rather than `\;`, this is *not* an option here due to the nature of the command line passed.)

An **efficient and robust<sup>[1]</sup>
 implementation that minimizes the number of child processes** created would look like this:

<sup>Note: I'm assuming *GNU* utilities here, due to use of `head -n -1` and `sort -h`.

Also, I'm limiting `find`'s output to *files* only (as opposed to directories), because `wc -l` only works on *files*.</sup>

```
paste <(find . -type f -exec du -h {} +) <(find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + | head -n -1) |
  awk -F'\t *' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {sub(" .+$", "", $3); print $1,$2,$3}' |
   sort -h -t$'\t' -k1,1
```

- Note the use of `-exec ... +` rather than `-exec ... \;`, which ensures that typically *all* input filenames are passed to a *single* invocation to the external utility (if not all filenames fit on a single command line, invocations are batched efficiently to make as few calls as possible).
- `wc -l {} +` invariably outputs a summary line, which `head -n -1` strips away, but also outputs filenames after each line count.
- `paste` combines the lines from each command (whose respective inputs are provided by a process substitution. `<(...)`) into a single output stream.
- The `awk` command then strips the extraneous filename that stems from `wc` from the end of each line.
- Finally, the `sort` command sorts the result by the 1st (`-k1,1`) tab-separated (`-t$'\t'`) column by human-readable numbers (`-h`), such as the numbers that `du -h` outputs (e.g., `1K`).

---

<sup>[1] As with any *line*-oriented processing, filenames with embedded *newlines* are not supported, but I do not consider this a real-world problem.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried it with find/-exec as well, but the escaping is hell. With a shell function it works pretty straight forward:

```
#!/bin/bash
function dir
{
    du=$(du -sh "$1" | awk '{print $1}')
    wc=$(wc -l < "$1")
    printf "%10s %10s %s\n" $du $wc "${1#./}"
}

printf "%10s %10s %s\n" "size" "lines" "name"
OIFS=$IFS; IFS=""
find . -type f -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' f; do dir "$f"; done
IFS=$OIFS
```

Using basishm read it is even kind of safe by using nul terminator. The IFS is needed to avoid read to truncate trailing blanks in filenames.

BTW: `$'\0'` does not really work (same as `''`) - but it makes the intention clear.

Sample output:

```
      size      lines name
      156K        708 sash
       16K         64 hostname
      120K        460 netstat
       40K        110 fuser
      644K       1555 dir/bash
       28K         82 keyctl
      2.3M       8067 vim
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your shell interprets the `$(...)`, so `find` doesn't get them. Escaping them doesn't help, either (`\$\(du -h {}\)`), as they become normal parameters to the commands, not command substitution.

In order to interpret them as command substitution is to call a new shell, either directly

```
find . -exec bash -c 'echo $(du -h {}) $(wc -l {})' \; | sort -h
```

or by creating a script and calling it from `find`.

Comment: @Hatshepsut: Sure, use `wc -l < {}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will break with filenames with embedded metacharacters such as spaces (and possibly with embedded globbing chars).
To fix that, you'd have to use `find . -exec bash -c 'echo "$(du -h "$1") $(wc -l <"$1")"' - {} \; | sort -h`
However, even though that fixes the OP's immediate problem and is alluringly short, this approach will perform 
poorly with large sets of input files, because it creates multiple child processes _per filename_.